# What is the best replacement for Windows' rand_s in Linux/POSIX?

Tags: linux, security, random, cryptography

The problem is not about randomness itself (we have rand), but in cryptographically secure PRNG. What can be used on Linux, or ideally POSIX? Does NSS have something useful?

**Clarification**: I know about /dev/random, but it may run out of entropy pool. And I'm not sure whether /dev/urandom is guaranteed to be cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/dev/random` (requires user input, eg mouse movements) or `/dev/urandom`.  The latter has an entropy pool and doesn't require any user input unless the pool is empty.

You can read from the pool like this:

```
char buf[100];
FILE *fp;
if (fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r")) {
    fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 100, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urandom) (my italics):

A counterpart to /dev/random is /dev/urandom ("unlocked" random source) which reuses the internal pool to produce more pseudo-random bits. This means that the call will not block, but the output may contain less entropy than the corresponding read from /dev/random. The *intent* is to serve as a *cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator*. This may be used for less secure applications.

Answer (score 3):

The `/dev/random` device is intended to be a source of cryptographically secure bits.