# Cryptographic secure octet in C

Tags: c

I wanted to create a cryptographic secure octet in c. I've heard, that the `rand()` function is not secure enough so I need an alternative. Do you have any ideas how to deal with this problem? Would be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: There is no such standard function in C, but cryptography libraries include secure rand functions. You must already be using such a library!

Comment: Can you recommend one library?

Comment: OpenSSL seems to be popular. Note that I am some guy on the internet who doesn't know much about cryptography, and I don't know what you intend to do exactly. My recommendations could be useless!

Comment: `FILE *f = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r"); printf("Random octet: %d\n", fgetc(f));`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually i just want to create a secure string out of 8 bits. Like:"abcd1234"

Comment: @squeamishossifrage so you mean i should write a textfile with dozens of bits an read them on different positions?

Comment: Your `abcd1234` example is 8 bytes, not 8 bits. Which do you mean?  The `/dev/urandom` device is a source of cryptographically secure random bytes on systems that support it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best replacement for Windows' rand\_s in Linux/POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120206/what-is-the-best-replacement-for-windows-rand-s-in-linux-posix)

Comment: Well, you can generate random bytes and XOR with plaintext of the same size. But you cannot reuse the same random bytes twice, unless your plaintext is also secure pseudo random. This has no practical application which I know of. There are many pitfalls in cryptography. I would recommend using a library which does all of this for you. By the way, what is your operating system?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Im currently working on linux and using visual studio Code. Thanks for your tip with the XOR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux, read /dev/urandom to get some random seed, then srandom(seed).
On bare metal, reading ADC values + some mathematics helped me in past.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I´m trying it with this pseudo File. I will post my code here if it´s working.